# Spring Error Response auto converted to Html from JSON

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am getting error response correctly when I am running the project in my end.

```
{
 "timestamp": "2018-05-30T10:16:00.065+0000",
 "status": 500,
 "error": "Internal Server Error",
 "message": "No login found for username :string",
 "path": "/gatepass/api/v1/logins/login"
 }
```

But when I deploy on server It automatically converts to HTML. How to fix this?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error</title>
      <style type="text/css">h1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} h2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} h3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} b {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} p {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} a.name {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}</style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error</h1>
      <hr class="line" />
      <p><b>Type</b> Status Report</p>
      <p><b>Message</b> No login found for username :string</p>
      <p><b>Description</b> The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.</p>
      <hr class="line" />
      <h3>Apache Tomcat/8.5.27</h3>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is the same response. The difference is that the web container writes the response onto the browser and hence the HTML markup showing up. You can have the 'produces' option in RequestMapping set to 'application/json'

Comment: I have done that. But still I get response in html format

Comment: Could you please share your code which is sending the response? And other relevant code snippets?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is fixed by creating a default error page such that the tomcat does not direct to error HTML page

Comment: How do you do it?

Answer (score 1):

That looks like your server (Tomcat) or your Web Application has a default 500 error page that is being applied.

Comment: I am using tomcat v8.5.27. And I don't want to redirect to that page. I need error in json format not html. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: I'm saying that I think you have either Tomcat or your app set up to use a default error page. So first, I'd look to see if that's the case. If it is, changing it to not do that would be a Tomcat question. And might break some other reason you want it to be that way as well. But also, are you sure you want a 500 error for this case? See https://www.codetinkerer.com/2015/12/04/choosing-an-http-status-code.html

Comment: Hey thanks. I think I should not send 500 status. 500 redirected to default error page which caused the error. But that was solved after creating the default error page. But the better solution is attaching the proper status in the exception. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

i think it may helps ,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/userAuthenticationDemo",method = RequestMethod.GET , produces="application/json")
  public ResponseEntity<?> userAuthenticationDemo(@RequestParam("username") String username, @RequestParam("password") String password, ) {

          System.out.println("Authentication hit");

              JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

              json.put("username", username);
              json.put("password", password);

JSONObject authRespObj = gstcService.userAuthenticationForPostalAppChecking(json);

              if(authRespObj != null){
                  authRespObj.put("isErrorFlag", false);
                  return new ResponseEntity<>(authRespObj, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.OK);
              }else{

                  throw new UserException("_USER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED");
              }
}
```

here for JSON data response we need to use `produces="application/json"`. 
and better to use Response Entity instead of @ResponseBody . noting is special but Response Entity can carry response with Http Status Codes.

if it helps please promote.